# Get descriptor value from a BLE node

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a newbie to Android app coding and I am currently writing an Android app to scan BLE beacons nearby and get the data inside the beacon. Currently I am using LightBlue Explorer which is an iOS app as a BLE beacon for broadcasting data.

I want my app to receive data broadcasted by the beacon. First of all, should I use 'descriptor' as a place for putting the data? (Since I can set the characteristic user description and descriptor value inside LightBlue Explorer) If so, how can I get the value of a descriptor in my app? For now, I can get the service and the characteristics of that beacon. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with beacons, but i have worked on BLE devices. SO i might say you a thing or two to start conversation thread.

BLE devices around you gives out broadcast information regarding the device itself necessary for establishing the connection with device itself.

So you cant directly access the data within the device without prior connection.
This is called **Generic Access Profile (GAP)**

Once after establishing the connection with the device and the app(Mobile) you have to use **Generic Attribute Profile (GATT)** to get data necessary for the device.

You can receive data after connection by two ways.

1) Write & Notify

2) Write & Read

1) In this you have to write necessary command on the specified write characteristic for specific service on the device and device will push the necessary data on the specific Notify characteristic. **Make sure the notify characteristic is enabled**

2) In this you have to write necessary command on the specified write characteristic for specific service on the device and then you have to request read to the device from the app, then from the read port you can get  the data given by the device.

I hope you get kinda of idea about BLE working. I have worked on BLE devices on Android side.

If any doubts just reply to thread.

To others if any correction you feel is needed, please reply.

Thank You.